# Code from python 2.7 to 3.5 (unicode)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode

I am really unfamiliar with python. I just have the code and wanted to upgrade the code to python 3.5.
I changed it and now there is one problem. I had the following code:

```
map(unicode.strip, set(list))
```

With Python 2.7 everyything works fine. But with Python 3.5 PyCharm cannot do anything with unicode. So, how do I have to change the code so that Python 3.5 can work with it?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't know that `str` is Unicode in Python 3; you can introduce subtle bugs if you try to run Python 2 script on Python 3 without understanding of encoding issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `unicode` to `str`.